# adding redirect page to google webmaster tools

Tags: http-status-code-301, google-search-console

I have two websites

short.com and long.com

All pages on short.com redirect to long.com

How do I add short.com to google webmaster tools?

Can I add two meta tags for the verification code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify short.com with TXT dns recored and ignore the websites redirects.
More info can be found over here https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176792

Comment: if short.com redirects with 301 with every page, do i even have to administer it?

Comment: Probably not, but you still can verify the website for whatever reason you need it